# spock reusable closure in mocks

Tags: groovy, spock

How can I reuse closures in spock mocks?

I can type closure as it go (mock.sth({closure}) but how can I create named clsoure to be reused or to increase code readability (mock.sth(hasStuffAsExpected))?

I have class:

```
class Link {
  String url
  boolean openInNewWindow
}
```

now there is service

```
interface LinkService {
  boolean checkStuff(Link link)
}
```

In my tests I would like to create something like this:

```
@Shared def linkIsOpenInNewWindow = { Link l -> l.isOpenInNewWindow }
@Shared Closure linkIsHttps = { Link l -> l.url.startsWith("https") }

expect:
    1 * linkService.checkStuff(linkIsHttps) >> true
    1 * linkService.checkStuff(linkIsOpenInNewWindow) >> false
```

And when I run this code it's always:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * linkService.checkStuff(linkIsHttps) >> true   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * linkService.checkStuff(Link@1234)
```

is there any way to achieve this and to create and use named reusable closures in spock?

Fake specification:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
@Grab('cglib:cglib:3.1') 
@Grab('org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.0.3') 

import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class Test extends Specification {

    LinkService linkService = Mock(LinkService)

    @Shared
    Closure openInNewWindow = { it.isOpenInNewWindw()}

    @Shared
    def httpsLink = { Link l -> l.url.startsWith("https") }

    @Shared
    def secureLink = new Link(
        url: "https://exmaple.com",
        openInNewWindw: false
    )

    @Shared
    def externalLink = new Link(
        url: "http://exmaple.com",
        openInNewWindw: true
    )

    def "failing closure test"() {
        when:
        def secureLinkResult = linkService.doStuff(secureLink)
        def externalLinkResult = linkService.doStuff(externalLink)

        then:
        secureLinkResult == 1
        externalLinkResult == 2

        1 * linkService.doStuff(httpsLink) >> 1
        1 * linkService.doStuff(openInNewWindow) >> 2
    }

    def "passing closure test"() {
        when:
        def secureLinkResult = linkService.doStuff(secureLink)
        def externalLinkResult = linkService.doStuff(externalLink)

        then:
        secureLinkResult == 1
        externalLinkResult == 2

        1 * linkService.doStuff({Link l -> l.url.startsWith("https")}) >> 1
        1 * linkService.doStuff({Link l -> l.openInNewWindw}) >> 2
    }
}

class Link {
    String url
    boolean openInNewWindw
}

interface LinkService {
    int doStuff(Link link)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this that way:

```
def "failing closure test"() {
    when:
    def secureLinkResult = linkService.doStuff(secureLink)
    def externalLinkResult = linkService.doStuff(externalLink)

    then:
    secureLinkResult == 1
    externalLinkResult == 2

    1 * linkService.doStuff({ httpsLink(it) }) >> 1
    1 * linkService.doStuff({ openInNewWindow(it) }) >> 2
}
```

Some explanation can be found [in this thread](http://spock-framework.3207229.n2.nabble.com/Closure-argument-constraint-in-variable-td7573426.html)

Comment: nope. It's not working. Closure is not executed.
`def httpsLink = { Link l -> {print("asd"); return l.url.startsWith("https")} }`
and asd text is not printed. It looks like closure is not executed

Comment: To make this work properly you need to `1 * linkService.doStuff({ httpsLink(it) })` Not exactly what I was hoping, but it's something ;)

Comment: I'm not sure why printing is not working, but when I changed secureLink definition to something that should break the test (eq. `url: "http://exmaple.com"`) then test failed, but without printing anything.

Comment: It's weird when  `def secureLink = new Link(url: "http://exmaple.com", openInNewWindw: false) (no https)`
and verification is: `1 * linkService.doStuff({ httpsLink }) >> 1`
then `JUnit 4 Runner, Tests: 1, Failures: 0, Time: 167`
It will keep passing unless I verify it with `{httpsLink(it)}`. I'm not sure what is happing. I'm using groovy 2.4.3 with java8

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for confusing comment. Using `{ httpsLink(it) }` as a matcher is working, so you can mark answer as a correct one.